# Dynamic object for interface variable C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with creating dynamic objects for interface variables.

Below is for the one workbook,worksheet and cells. So then I can create like this

// excelFileBo  contains the excel workbook locations and sheetnames.

```
List<ExcelFileBo> excelFileBo ;
    IWorkbook wbi1 = workbookSet.Workbooks.Open(exFileBo.WBLocation);
    SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet ws1 = wbi1.Worksheets[exFileBo.WBSheetName];
    SpreadsheetGear.IRange wc1 = ws1.Cells;
```

But how to create objects for multiple workbooks,worksheets and cells dynamically ?

```
 foreach (ExcelFileBo exFileBo in excelFileBo)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(exFileBo.WBLocation))
                {
                     // how to create IWorkbook objects,IWorksheet object and IRange dynamically for all excel workbooks.
                }                
            }
```

Please help me to do this ?

Comment: Well it sounds like you want use a collection... I don't see where "dynamic objects" come in here. Could you clarify your question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your first step is to read from database all the required info. Then you just create the cells using IRange

I would write it like this

```
string workSheetSQL = "Select * From [WorkSheetTable]";
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
using (SqlCommand sheetCommand = new SqlCommand(workSheetSQL, cnn))
{
    using (SqlDataReader sheetReader = sheetCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sheetReader.Read())
        {
            SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook();
            SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            SpreadsheetGear.IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

            // Set the worksheet name.
            worksheet.Name = sheetReader["WBSheetName"].ToString();
            //I assume FunctionWBId value is foreign key for cell Table, otherwise remove WHERE clause from following sql query
            string cellsSQL = "Select * From [CellsTable] where FunctionWBId = "+sheetReader["FunctionWBId"].ToString();
            // Load cell values.

            using (SqlCommand cellCommand = new SqlCommand(cellsSQL, cnn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader cellReader = cellCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (cellReader.Read())
                    {
                        cells[cellReader["ExcelCellNo"]ToString()].Value = cellReader["IOValue"].ToString();
                        //Add more properties to each cell if you wish in the same way
                    }
                }                   
            }
            workbook.SaveAs(sheetReader["WBLocation"].ToString()); 
            //Add more properties to workbook if you wish in the same way
        }
    }
}
}
```